# Stripping data from xml in SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

One of my tables with xml datatype has the following xml information:

```
<RequestMetaData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MetaData Type="DocImport">
    <Keywords>
      <Key Name="Zone" Value="MIO" />
      <Key Name="ClassificationStrategy" Value="NeedClassification" />
      <Key Name="Folder" Value="0456e6ca" />
    </Keywords>
  </MetaData>
  <MetaData Type="SourceResponse">
    <Keywords>
      <Key Name="NotificationResponse_20180427-150426" Value="Received successful response from Source" />
    </Keywords>
  </MetaData>
</RequestMetaData>
```

I need to write an SQL query to fetch the value of Classification strategy based on key name.

I have added the xml in a variable @xml and used the following code. It is returning NULL.

```
select A.b.value('ClassificationStrategy[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS CS
FROM @xml.nodes('/RequestMetaData/MetaData/Keywords') AS A(b)
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Care to share any of your code with us?

Comment: I have added the xml in a variable @xml and used the following code. It is returning NULL.
select 
A.b.value('ClassificationStrategy[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS CS
FROM @xml.nodes('/RequestMetaData/MetaData/Keywords') AS A(b)

Comment: I added the code in your comment to your question. Try qualifying the element and adding a predicate: `@xml.value('data(/RequestMetaData/MetaData/Keywords/Key[@Name="ClassificationStrategy"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')`

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your XML in various ways. Use a simple `.value()` with an `XPath/XQuery` expression to retrieve a single value, use `.query` to retrieve a part of the XML or use `.nodes()` to return repeated elements as derived table:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<RequestMetaData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MetaData Type="DocImport">
    <Keywords>
      <Key Name="Zone" Value="MIO" />
      <Key Name="ClassificationStrategy" Value="NeedClassification" />
      <Key Name="Folder" Value="0456e6ca" />
    </Keywords>
  </MetaData>
  <MetaData Type="SourceResponse">
    <Keywords>
      <Key Name="NotificationResponse_20180427-150426" Value="Received successful response from Source" />
    </Keywords>
  </MetaData>
</RequestMetaData>';

--Read the whole lot
SELECT md.value('@Type','nvarchar(max)') AS MetaDataType
      ,k.value('@Name','nvarchar(max)') AS KeyName
      ,k.value('@Value','nvarchar(max)') AS KeyValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/RequestMetaData/MetaData') A(md)
OUTER APPLY md.nodes('Keywords/Key') B(k);

--Get one key's value by name (anywhere in the doc)
DECLARE @keyName VARCHAR(100)='ClassificationStrategy';
SELECT @xml.value('(//Key[@Name=sql:variable("@keyName")]/@Value)[1]','nvarchar(max)');

--Use the meta data type as additional filter (if key names are not unique per doc)
DECLARE @kName VARCHAR(100)='ClassificationStrategy';
DECLARE @mdType VARCHAR(100)='DocImport';
SELECT @xml.value('(/RequestMetaData
                    /MetaData[@Type=sql:variable("@mdType")]
                    /Keywords
                    /Key[@Name=sql:variable("@kName")]
                    /@Value)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```